# Tesseract + OpenCV + linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, tesseract

I have developed an OCR application on Windows using OpenCV and Tesseract. Now all I want to do is to write same application over Linux (Ubuntu 12.10) in C++. And I don't have any experience in Linux development. I don't know where to start. All I want is developing environment in which I would able to link these two libraries OpenCV and Tesseract.

Please suggest me. I have tried searching Google but failed. Maybe I am not searching with good keywords. As I am totally new in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that you compiled OpenCV on your system, as OpenCV's linux bundle hasn't got pre-compiled libs (unlike Windows bundle). Follow [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html).

For a starting point, build up Eclipse as IDE and follow [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html). It shouldn't be so hard to adopt if you already used Visual Studio (MSVC Windows compiler).

Later on, it would be wise to learn about gcc (official linux compiler for your c++ code) and its syntax, and maybe together with CMake. Because learning the terminal and g++ syntax suddenly accelerates the development process. Linux has got many opportunities for a developer, such as pkg-config, which links all the libs and headers automatically (well, almost). You can also go for learning CMake for cross platform development and let it use "gcc" by default; example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html).

Also note that, using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), you can actually compile & build linux binaries on a Windows platform. For the opposite; check [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Good luck.

**EDIT: other cross platform solutions**

[VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/linux/)

[Qt](http://qt-project.org/)